# R recursive merge on hierarchy data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a child and parent field for accounts from a gnucash mysql db. I would like to store the account hierarchy in a data frame. In the past, I have used recursive joins in mySQL, but it gets cumbersome as the hierarchy gets deeper. You also have to know how many levels your tree goes. I am hoping there is a simpler way in R to build the hierarchy (with or without the knowledge of the max depth).

Sample data:

```
account_id <- c(1:11)
account_name <- c('root_account','dining', 'food', 'discretionary_expense',
                  'expenses', 'base_salary_wife', 'base_salary_husband',
                  'base_salary', 'salary', 'taxable_income',
                  'income')
account_parentid <- c(NA,3,4,5,1,8,8,9,10,11,1)
test.data <- data.frame(account_id, account_name, account_parentid)
```

Desired output:

```
 account_id          account_name account_parentid lvl2_parentid lvl3_parentid lvl4_parentid lvls
1           1          root_account               NA            NA            NA            NA   NA
2           2                dining                3             4             6            NA    4
3           3                  food                4             5            NA            NA    3
4           4 discretionary_expense                5            NA            NA            NA    2
5           5              expenses                1            NA            NA            NA    1
6           6      base_salary_wife                8             9            10            11    5
7           7   base_salary_husband                8             9            10            11    5
8           8           base_salary                9            10            11            NA    4
9           9                salary               10            11            NA            NA    3
10         10        taxable_income               11            NA            NA            NA    2
11         11                income                1            NA            NA            NA    1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the data.tree package to work with hierarchic data:

Get test data:

```
account_id <- c(1:11)
account_name <- c('root_account','dining', 'food', 'discretionary_expense',
                  'expenses', 'base_salary_wife', 'base_salary_husband',
                  'base_salary', 'salary', 'taxable_income',
                  'income')
account_parentid <- c(NA,3,4,5,1,8,8,9,10,11,1)
test.data <- data.frame(account_id, account_parentid, account_name, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Convert to data.tree structure:

```
library(data.tree)
tree1 <- FromDataFrameNetwork(test.data[-1,])
tree1$account_name <- 'root_account'
```

Display:

```
ToDataFrameTree(tree1, account = 'name', 'account_name', 'pathString')
```

This will show like so:

```
               levelName account          account_name    pathString
1  1                           1          root_account             1
2   ¦--5                       5              expenses           1/5
3   ¦   °--4                   4 discretionary_expense         1/5/4
4   ¦       °--3               3                  food       1/5/4/3
5   ¦           °--2           2                dining     1/5/4/3/2
6   °--11                     11                income          1/11
7       °--10                 10        taxable_income       1/11/10
8           °--9               9                salary     1/11/10/9
9               °--8           8           base_salary   1/11/10/9/8
10                  ¦--6       6      base_salary_wife 1/11/10/9/8/6
11                  °--7       7   base_salary_husband 1/11/10/9/8/7
```

Not part of the question, but where it really gets interesting is when you want to sum up over hierarchies, etc. See the data.tree vignettes [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) and [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=data.tree/vignettes/applications.html).